# Xcode, fetch Facebook hometown name

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am beginner in ObjectiveC programming language.
I developing application, using Facebook.
I try to fetch Hometown name.

Now, i want copy "Sveti Martin na Muri" to string to display in tableview.

I use:

```
FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
```

and output is:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"hometown"]);

{
id = 107836872573218;
name = "Sveti Martin na Muri";
}
```

The same problem i have with relationship, work, location and education.

How can I access only name?

Sorry for my bad English.
greetings from Croatia.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
[result objectForKey:@"hometown"]
```

returns a `NSDictionary` with two field `id` and `name`.

You can access the name like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[result objectForKey:@"hometown"] objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

Comment: @user2945601: With pleasure :)

Comment: I have one more question.
I have connected with my profile and all data did shown, but whoa i connect with other user profile, only name, and birthday did shown?

How can i fix that? I need token? how?

I am beginner and no have experience with that.